# Help with program upload problem

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, uploading

I'm going to upload some code to my LeArm using an Arduino board. I connected the RX and TX pins of the LeArm to the Arduino, but I got an error message when I tried to upload the code.

I'm not sure if I made the connections correctly. Does anyone have any tips on how to upload the programs successfully?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Diagrams and actual code or error messages rather than photos of them, will help a great deal. If you update your question, please edit the question itself rather than adding comments. But from what I can read of the error messages (board not replying), either: the IDE has not got the right port selected, it has not got the correct board-type selected, the connections to your board are incorrect, or the board doesn't have the correct (or any) bootloader. That's about all I can get from what you've provided. But check out those 4 things thoroughly; one of them is the cause of your failure.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Is the Arduino Mega you have a "Chinese" version? If it is, try installing [these drivers](https://www.arduined.eu/ch340-windows-10-driver-download/) and try again.